# How can I compile weka-scr.jar in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.5

Hi Everybody I am trying to compile ready source code in netbeans for example

weka.scr.jar so please anyone tell me in detail how can I do it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean *weka-src.jar*?  If so, then the instructions for compiling with Netbeans appears to be provided here: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Netbeans+6.0+%28weka-src.jar%29

The instructions appear to be for NetBeans version 6.0, but a quick glance through the screenshots gives me the impression that their instructions are fairly generic and should more or less work for later versions such as 6.9.

The important thing to note is that weka-src.jar is a compressed file, much like a zip file. You need to extract the actual source code files from the .jar file before anything can be compiled.